# Datepicker doesn't work when I click second time

Tags: angularjs

I have a datepicker on angular.js:

```
<input  type="text" 
        class="form-control" 
        datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
        ng-model="dt" 
        is-open="opened" 
        min-date="minDate" 
        max-date="'2015-06-22'" 
        datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
        ng-required="true" 
        close-text="Close">
```

When I click the first time on button , work well, but when I click again , it did  work .

I try this:

```
$scope.open = function ($event) {
     $event.preventDefault();
     $event.stopPropagation();
     $scope.opened = true;
};
```

and this:

```
$scope.open = function ($event) {
     $event.stopPropagation();
     $scope.opened = true;
};
```

Comment: what  is expected second click flow?

Answer (score 1):

Because your button doing same i.e. setting variable to true so you don't get any effect on screen. try this:

```
$scope.open = function ($event) {
     //change this
     $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;

     $event.preventDefault();
     $event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: No, don`t worked. I do like this on html: ng-click(opened=true;$event.stopPropagation()); and worked. anyway thank you.